# K8s fault tolerance

Tags: kubernetes, fault-tolerance

I was going through the differences between Swarm vs K8s one of the **cons of Swarm is that it has limited fault tolerance functionality**. How does K8s achieve fault tolerance, is it via  K8s multi-master. Please share your inputs

Answer (score 4):

Yes! In order to achieve Kubernetes fault-tolerance is recommended to have multiples Control Planes (master) nodes and if you are running in cloud providers multiples availability zones are recommended.

> The Control Plane’s components make global decisions about the cluster (for example, scheduling), as well as detecting and responding to cluster events (for example, starting up a new [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/) when a deployment’s `replicas` field is unsatisfied).

Basically, the control plane is composed by theses components:

[kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-apiserver) - Exposes the Kubernetes API. Is the front for Kubernetes control plane

[etcd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#etcd) - Key/Value Kubernetes' backing store for cluster data

[kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-scheduler) - Responsible for watches for newly created pods with no assigned node, and selects a node for them to run on

[kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-controller-manager) - One of controller responsibility is maintain the correct number of pods for every replication  controller, populate endpoints objects and responding when nodes go down.

[cloud-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#cloud-controller-manager) - Interact with the underlying cloud providers,

Every cluster need 1 worker nodes at least, the work nodes is responsible to run your workloads.

> Here’s the diagram of a Kubernetes cluster with all the components tied together:

[image]

For more info see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all kubernetes control plane components are either clustered (etcd), run a leader election (controllers), or flat (apiserver). Traditionally you run three control plane nodes but you can do 5 in some complex topologies.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by apiserver is flat?

Comment: All instances of kube-apiserver are equivalent, it's a horizontally scaled web application.